# NSLocale currency symbol, show before or after amount value

Tags: objective-c, ios, storekit, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

I am using `StoreKit` to implement an in app purchase store in my application.

I have a custom design and it means that the value of the price should be white and large, and the currency symbol smaller, darker and aligned to the top of the price value.

I can get the currency symbol without any problems by using the `NSLocale` in `SKproduct`'s `priceLocale` property, and the value of the price in the `price` property.

My problem is knowing when I should put the currency symbol before the price and when to put it after the price.

Examples:

- $5,99
- 0,79€

I could easily use the `NSNumberFormatter` to get this worked out "out of the box", but since my layout defines a different style for the value and currency symbol, I've found myself in a position where a more manual workaround is required.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Could you parse the string produced by an `NSNumberFormatter` by looking for non-numeric substrings at both the beginning and end of the string, then evaluate which one is non-empty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The locale object doesn't seem to provide this information directly, but of course the number formatter must know it. You're not supposed to ask (new-style) number formatters for their `format` directly, although that'll probably work, and you can then look for the currency symbol, `¤`, in the format string.

Possibly better would be to create a `CFNumberFormatter`, which does explicitly allow you to view its format, and then inspect that string:

```
// NSLocale and CFLocale are toll-free bridged, so if you have an existing
// NSNumberFormatter, you can get its locale and use that instead.
CFLocaleRef usLocale = CFLocaleCreate(NULL, CFSTR("en_US"));
CFNumberFormatterRef usFormatter = CFNumberFormatterCreate(NULL, usLocale, kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle);
CFLocaleRef frLocale = CFLocaleCreate(NULL, CFSTR("fr_FR"));
CFNumberFormatterRef frFormatter = CFNumberFormatterCreate(NULL, frLocale, kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle);

NSString * usString = (__bridge NSString *)CFNumberFormatterGetFormat(usFormatter);
NSString * frString = (__bridge NSString *)CFNumberFormatterGetFormat(frFormatter);

NSUInteger loc = ([usString rangeOfString:@"¤"]).location;
NSLog(@"Currency marker at beginning for US? %@", (loc == 0) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
loc = ([frString rangeOfString:@"¤"]).location;
NSLog(@"Currency marker at end for FR? %@", (loc == [frString length] - 1) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: This is very interesting. I think I can use this. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

You have everything you need in your `SKProduct` instance. Just use `NSNumberFormatter` in conjunction and that's it.

```
NSNumberFormatter *priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];        

for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
    [priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    NSLog(@"Price for %@ is: %@",product.localizedTitle,[priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price]);
}
```

#### Swift 3+

```
let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
priceFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

for product in response.products {
    priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
    let localizedPrice = priceFormatter.string(from: product.price)
    print("Price for \(product.localizedTitle) is: \(localizedPrice)")
}
```

Comment: Agree, this is a better solution. I would just move the first two lines inside the for loop to outside of it... minor optimization, but no need to create a priceFormatter instance for every product in the iteration.

Comment: Hi, thanks, just a followup, this wouldn't really solve my problem because in my case I needed specific font for the currency string, not the price value, so that's why I needed to know if the currency string was before or after the price value.

Comment: Ironically this puts yen before the value but apple in app purchases puts yen after the value. Apple does not use price formatter for their very own in app purchases?

Answer (score 3):

I use this solution (Swift):

```
let currencyFormat = CFNumberFormatterGetFormat(CFNumberFormatterCreate(nil, locale, .CurrencyStyle)) as NSString
let positiveNumberFormat = currencyFormat.componentsSeparatedByString(";")[0] as NSString
let currencySymbolLocation = positiveNumberFormat.rangeOfString("¤").location
return (currencySymbolLocation == 0) ? .Before : .After
```

The accepted answer should be fixed since the `CFNumberFormatterGetFormat` sometimes (for some locales) returns double value: `¤##,#00.0;-¤##,#00.0` which includes a negative number format. Make sure to parse that string.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

An extension function on `Locale`:

```
extension Locale {
    func isCurrencySymbolAtStart() -> Bool {
        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        currencyFormatter.locale = self
        
        let positiveFormat = currencyFormatter.positiveFormat as NSString
        let currencySymbolLocation = positiveFormat.range(of: "¤").location
        
        return currencySymbolLocation == 0
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let displayCurrencySymbolAtStart = NSLocale.current.isCurrencySymbolAtStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was to set the decimal style and set the minimum number of significant digits.

```
static NSNumberFormatter *NumberFormatter;

if (!NumberFormatter) {
    NumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [NumberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [NumberFormatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
    [NumberFormatter setMinimumSignificantDigits:2];
}

NSString *formattedNumberString = [NumberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(valueInEuro)];

NSString *stringInEuro = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"€ %@", formattedNumberString];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension of SKProduct, putting things where they belong imho.

```
extension SKProduct
{
    var localizedPrice: String {
        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        numberFormatter.locale = self.priceLocale
        numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .Behavior10_4
        return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(self.price)!
    }
}
```

That way of formatting is, by the way, also exactly what Apple suggests in the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html), section [Retrieving Product Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW5).