# How do I make a CFLocale for a target language?

Tags: swift, swift3, locale, core-foundation

In Objective C, one can create a CFLocale as follows (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12254356/5951226) in 2012):

- `CFLocaleRef myLocale = CFLocaleCopyCurrent()` for the current locale; or:
- `CFLocaleRef myLocale = CFLocaleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("ja"))`, for a target locale. The locale name comes from the rightmost column of the [ISO 639-1/639-2 table](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php), which Apple specifies as their standard for language codes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html).*

****Note***: very old code examples refer to long language codes like 'Japanese', as [may be expected](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1391/_index.html) by versions of Mac OS X older than 10.4.

How does one create a CFLocale in Swift 3, as the API appears to have changed in several ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFLocale` is toll-free bridged to `NSLocale`, so you can simply call

```
 let myLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ja")
 // or
 let myLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: NSLocale.canonicalLocaleIdentifier(from: "Japanese"))
```

depending on whether you have a ISO 639-1 language code or not.

The corresponding Swift 3 "overlay value type" `Locale`
(which is used by `Calendar`, `DateFormatter`, ...,
compare [SE-0069 Mutability and Foundation Value Types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md))
can similarly be created with

```
let myLocale = Locale(identifier: "ja")
// or 
let myLocale = Locale(identifier: Locale.canonicalIdentifier(from: "Japanese"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the API changes to Swift since the Objective-C example given from 2012:

- *CFLocaleRef* has been replaced by *CFLocale*.
- *CFStringRef* has been replaced by *CFString*, which may be created by a regular *String* cast to *CFString* type: `"ja" as CFString!`.
- [CFLocaleCreate()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1542689-cflocalecreate) now expects a *CFLocaleIdentifier* rather than just a *CFString*, so we must provide one using [CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1542757-cflocalecreatecanonicallanguagei).

This can be done with the following two lines:

```
let localeIdentifier: CFLocaleIdentifier = CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "ja" as CFString!)
let locale: CFLocale = CFLocaleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, localeIdentifier)
```